# jQuery update html element text without affect the HTML children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a litle problem and I don't know how to fix it.

I have an HTML hierarchy like the one here

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="el_01">
        <div class="title">
            Title Goes Here
            <span class="openClose"></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I like to do is to modify the "Title Goes Here".

What I have try is :

```
$('#el_01 title').text('New Title Goes Here');
```

But that also remove the :

```
<span class="openClose"></span>
```

Is there a way to update only the "Title Goes Here" without affect the span element ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can edit the text node directly by accessing the DOM element, and getting its `firstChild`.

```
$('#el_01 .title')[0].firstChild.data = 'New Title Goes Here';
```

If there are several `.title` elements, you can do it in an `.each()` loop.

```
$('#el_01 .title').each(function(i,el) {
    el.firstChild.data = 'New Title Goes Here';
});
```

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks ! I will check it as answer after a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solution:

**Either:** Wrap the text in a span of its own:

```
<div class="title">
    <span class="text">Title Goes Here</span>
    <span class="openClose"></span>
</div>
```

... and update that:

```
$('#el_01 .text').text('New Title Goes Here');
```

**Or:** Keep a copy of the `openClose` span and re-insert it after updating the text:

```
var openClose = $('#el_01 .title .openClose');
$('#el_01 .title').text('New Title Goes Here').append(openClose);
```