# Changing a span's text, leaving children unaffected

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following markup, how can I change just the text within the parent span - with either javascript or jQuery?

```
<td class="cartItemTotal">
    <span>
        <span class="currency_sign">£</span>
        25.00
    </span>
</td>
```

I tried the following two (based on [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/in-jquery-how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605974/jquery-update-html-element-text-without-affect-the-html-children-elements) SO questions), but nothing happens with either.

```
(1)

$this.find('.cartItemTotal > span').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).filter(':first').replaceWith( itemTotal.toFixed(2) );

(2)

$this.find('.cartItemTotal > span')[0].firstChild.data = itemTotal.toFixed(2);
```

NB: "`$this`" refers to the current `<tr>` the table data element resides in.

Comment: I don't see `cartItemTotal` inside your HTML

Comment: Apologies @DavidStarkey - amended.

Comment: have you thought about un-nesting your spans?

`<span class="currency_sign">£</span>`
`<span>25.00</span>`

Comment: @MikeB - I have, but the CMS I'm using doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors don't make sense compared to your markup, but if you can get to the `.total > span`, you can get the DOM element `[0]`, and use `.lastChild`.

```
$(".total > span").each(function(i, el) {
    console.log(el.lastChild.data);
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/Y3m4b/

---

So your last code example was almost there. Just needed to use `.lastChild` instead of `.firstChild`.

```
$this.find('.cartItemTotal > span')[0].lastChild.data = itemTotal.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Because it's the last child of the `.total > span` element.

Comment: Although the others clearly work in their respective fiddles, this is the only answer that would actually work in my page. Strange, but true.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery does'nt really do well with textNodes, but using the native `nextSibling` you can get the textNode following the `.currency_sign` element :

```
$('.currency_sign').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = 'new value';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHfsa/1/)

I'm using `get(0)` to get the first native DOM element in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with contents() and filter() to get the textNodes.

```
var node = $(".cartItemTotal>span").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
node.last().replaceWith( document.createTextNode( "1.99" ));
```

Running Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eSemE/